# Android app future name in google play store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I'm planning to upload an android app that I have created to `Google Play Store`, and I want to know the link to the app in the store so I can insert it to somewhere in my app (where you can share the app).

**In which format will the link to the actual app in the play store be?** Will it be in the following format? :

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details/id=package_name ?

I couldn't find an answer to it anywhere online.. I think it will be related to the package name but I'm not sure..

Comment: do you mean if already publish in google play?

Comment: @ntaloventi no, what I meant is the name that it will be in. I'll update the question.

Comment: sorry already post answer, you just answer your own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm get used with some like update screen add add listener to click and use intent to find it in google play, something like this:

`Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getActivity().getPackageName()));
startActivity(i);`

please try it!

Comment: In all my apps a similar method was used. It works well.

Answer (score 1):

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.org.appname

where "com.org.appname" is your package name.